# In TeX, how do I define the label style for compactenum globally?

Tags: latex, tex

I have a couple of `compactenum` elements in my document. I would like define color and type for all labels in a **more elegant** way than this:

```
\begin{compactenum}[label=\textcolor{black}{\arabic*.}]
\item lorem
\item ipsum
\item dolor
\end{compactenum}

\begin{compactenum}[label=\textcolor{black}{\arabic*.}]
\item sit
\item amet
\end{compactenum}
```

How do I set it globally the most elegant way? Is there a way where I can define the behavior for compactenum without using `[...]` at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is `\setdefaultenum{\color{black} 1.}{}{}{}`. It will set your outer label to be black arabic label. For more information, refer to [paralist documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/paralist.pdf) Here's a **MCVE**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist,xcolor}
\setdefaultenum{\color{black} 1.}{}{}{}% What you need!
% The 1. is the equivalent of \arabic*. 
% The other {}{}{} refer to the list levels,
% i.e. {second level}{third level}{fourth level}
\begin{document}
    \begin{compactenum}
        \item lorem
        \item ipsum
        \item dolor
    \end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```